# Display correct number of rows

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to print a 3x3 table of random 0s and 1s using one-dimensional arrays. Afterwards I want to print lines that consist of all 1s or all 0s (kind of like tic tac toe), but for now I can't get the 3x3 display I need.

```
    int[] row1 = new int[3];
    int[] row2 = new int[3];
    int[] row3 = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        row1[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
        row2[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
        row3[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
        System.out.print(row1[i]);
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print(row2[i]);
        System.out.print(row3[i]);

      }
```

The output (layout) is:

```
0 

001

110

00
```

This is the closest I have come to displaying the numbers in three rows and three columns. I've tried print, println, and printf but I can't get it. I know there might be some unnecessary code but at this point I am at a loss. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Put that `System.out.print("\n");` at the last of all your print statements! Given that you have blank lines between your output lines, I suggest you use `System.out.println` everywhere instead.

Comment: @BhargavRao that suggestion makes the rows printed as columns

Comment: *but for now I can't get the 3x3 display I need.* --- Is too vague! Therefore @Shar1er80 We need the OP to clarify his stance and mention as to what is the *3x3* he needs. I hope you got my point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your variables are named as rows, they should not be displayed as they are being filled with numbers.

After you fill your rows with numbers, loop through them individually and print them.

```
int[] row1 = new int[3];
int[] row2 = new int[3];
int[] row3 = new int[3];

// Fill your rows with numbers
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    row1[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
    row2[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
    row3[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
}

printRow(row1);
printRow(row2);
printRow(row3);
```

The printRow method would look like:

```
private void printRow(int[] row)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(row[i]);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Then your output would look like (Depending on what random numbers were assigned):

```
010 
101 
010
```

Comment: What do you mean "add an output as displayed"?  For now I'm just giving a suggestion that will display his 3x3 table.  Even manouti makes a good suggestion for getting a 3x3 table.

Comment: Now you know the importance of adding outputs. All the best and good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to place the newline *after* the three `print` statements display a row:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    row1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    row2[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    row3[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    System.out.print(row1[i]);
    System.out.print(row2[i]);
    System.out.print(row3[i]);
    System.out.print("\n");

}
```

In this case, it's better to rename the arrays to be `col1`, `col2` and `col3` since each iteration prints a row by selecting an element from the columns. Since you're randomly generating 0s and 1s, it shouldn't differ.

```
int[] col1 = new int[3];
int[] col2 = new int[3];
int[] col3 = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    col1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    col2[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    col3[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    System.out.print(col1[i]);
    System.out.print(col2[i]);
    System.out.print(col3[i]);
    System.out.print("\n");

}
```

Comment: This prints the rows as columns

Comment: @Shar1er80 Then the OP can rename to reflect columns instead. Won't matter here since values are random.

Comment: I agree with this for displaying a 3x3 table

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
      int[] row1 = new int[3];
int[] row2 = new int[3];
int[] row3 = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    row1[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
    row2[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
    row3[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 2);

  }

  for (int i : row1)
  {
    System.out.print(i);
  }

    System.out.print("\n");

  for (int i : row2)
  {
    System.out.print(i);
  }


    System.out.print("\n");
  for (int i : row3)
  {
    System.out.print(i);
  }

    System.out.print("\n");
}
```